# Pressing Alt+Tab causes Microsoft Edge's to switch into tab rather than app

Tags: task-manager, microsoft-edge, alt-tab

**tl;dr** *Sometimes when I hit <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in Microsoft Edge, I am switching to another tab (like I'd press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>) instead of switching to some other app in Windows 10. This is terribly annoying and counter-productive. What is causing it (is this a bug or yet another Microsoft invention) and how to get rid of this?*

---

I've been using Microsoft Edge for years on many PCs. Always without any problems. Since yesterday I have a brand new PC and I am getting and awfully weird experience in Edge. When  when I hit <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, instead of switching to another active app, I am rather switching to some other tab in Edge itself.

A closer look told me that for some reason beyond my imagination, my Edge shows some (but not all!) of my tabs as a separate tasks / processes / apps. And most likely this is causing all the problems.

An example -- Two of five Edge's tabs are shown as a separate windows:

[image]

When there are two Edge's *windows* opened up intentionally by user then things gets even worse. Here:

[image]

you have an Edge with:

- 15 tabs opened up in first window
- 1 single tab opened up in second window

Instead of showing (as expected) two elements in Task Manager, I can clearly see... *seven* items. For some reason six of fifteen tabs opened up in first windows are seen by Windows as a separate apps or tasks running.

This drives me crazy and actually causes any reasonable work with Edge completely impossible. Is there any explanation for this behavior? Is there any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the Windows *Settings* app and go to *System → Multitasking*. Find a setting labelled "Pressing Alt+Tab shows":

[image]

And select "Open windows only".

Comment: I don't have that option on my 1909 system.  This limited to specific versions?

Comment: In that case you might find in your Edge settings instead. (The general feature of "tabs as windows" has probably existed as far back as Windows 7, but the app has to decide to implement it, so it was normally controlled through the browser's settings.)

Comment: Perhaps try resetting Edge.  Start, Settings, Apps. Scroll down to Edge. Repair and Reset and then restart the computer and test.

Comment: @user1686 - I have a option called `Pressing Alt+Tab shows` but `Open Windows Only` isn't an option.

Comment: @John - Are suggesting that resetting Edge will do something to the Settings application?  (By the way I already know the option is version specific)

Comment: @Ramhound: ¯\\_(ツ)\_/¯

Comment: If the version is older and does not have the multitasking settings, then reset might work. I am suggesting "try it".